# How to make "Read More" content push down page content

Tags: html, css, togglebutton

I've put a (CSS) "Read More" toggle button on one paragraph on my page. When I click on "Read More", the extra text runs into the paragraph below. How do I make the content below more down? I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what to try. Any help appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 162, 38, 0.55);
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cultureHist"></div>
<div class="descriptionText">
  <h4>Where History Abounds</h4><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="histAbounds">
  <p class="read-more-wrap" style="text-align: left">Tishomingo County was once the Marriage Capital of the South. Numerous couples came to the old Tishomingo County Courthouse to “tie the knot,” due to marriage license requirements being so easy. Tishomingo County is extremely rich with historical and
    cultural stories. Historical homes, the Battle of Iuka and other Civil War skirmishes.<span class="read-more-target"> If you are a history buff, you'll want to see our historical cemeteries, museums, stately old buildings and historical markers that celebrate the romance and keep the memories of a bygone era alive. The resources found on these pages are only glimpses into our rich history and illustrate not only why people of many cultures converged here, but how they changed the world.</span></p>
  <label for="histAbounds" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div data-aos="fade-zoom-in" data-aos-offset="0" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-duration="1000">

  <div class="animationContainer">
    <div class="retirement"></div>
    <div class="descriptionText">
      <h4>Your Retirement Haven</h4><br><br>Tishomingo County is one of the best places to retire. According to Kiplinger, Mississippi ranked #4 as the most tax-friendly state for retirees. Retirees do not pay income tax on retirement income. Social security
      income is not taxed, regardless of total income.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: More down? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. "Your Retirement Haven" paragraph have to go more down? Do you have to add a sort of `padding-top` to that section when someone clicks on "Read more" button?

Comment: Hm, why does it work here and not my browser? When I click on "Read More" on here, it works like I want it to ("Your Retirement Haven" moves down and the text above does not run into it).

Comment: Ah... So here your code works well! (^_^;) Maybe another CSS rules break your layout? Maybe HTML is similar but not the same?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I don' know how copying/pasting it here fixes it. Ha.

Comment: Well, if here your code works well, you could ask to SO to host your site! ;-) Seriously, the problem is not in this code and this is a step to find the real problem. Good debug! :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I found that it works in media queries below 1024px. which is why it works here. I will make adjustments. Thank you! You helped me think it through.